# PHP - How check which checbox is submitted?

Tags: php, forms

I have multiple forms in a page (some sort of "on/off" for different actions).

E.g.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ @SERVER.REQUEST_URI }}">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_action" value="1" />
        <input type="checkbox" class="switch-checkbox" name="active[1]" value="1" />
    </fieldset>
</form>


<form method="post" action="{{ @SERVER.REQUEST_URI }}">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_action" value="2" />
        <input type="checkbox" class="switch-checkbox" name="active[2]" value="1" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

In the `$_POST` submitted, from 1st form, I have this:

```
active[1]   1
id_action   2
id_action   1
```

And in 2nd one form I have this:

```
active[1]   1
active[2]   2
id_action   2
id_action   1
```

I need to receive only one id_action at time. Could please help me? Thank you.

Comment: From your code, there is no reason why this should happen. Please show the actual HTML code that is generated. (Or better, go [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) it yourself first of all.)

Comment: This is the actual HTML code (and menu and <p> tags that are not important.... ;-) )

Comment: CBroe you are right. This is my fault (on Jquery, not HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_action" value="2" />
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_action[2]" value="1" />
```

and similar with the fist box. Your sending both checkboxes correctly but not the hiddens

Comment: Value of the hidden input with name id_action is exactly the ID of the action... It could be also a value of... 1543... So (I think) your solution is not pratical.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="{{ @SERVER.REQUEST_URI }}">
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="id_action1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="switch-checkbox" name="active[]" value="1" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<form method="post" action="{{ @SERVER.REQUEST_URI }}">
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="id_action2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="switch-checkbox" name="active[]" value="2" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: @sineverba i have changed the code, just check if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You should give different name and value for each of the checkbox. if you are using php then its quite simple.

then after submitting the form use this code.

output will be:

id_action =>1
id_actoin1 =>2

if you want you can use only one $_POST[];